# OOP player implementation libgdx

Tags: java, android, oop, libgdx

I would like some suggestions for the implementation object of the player. 
the player can have 2 textures that will be chosen depending on the button pressed, for example, the right arrow will display a texture to the left while another texture.

I have implemented the interface inputprocessor in the class of player but I do not know why it does not seem very fair and very dynamic, so I would like some suggestions from you

thank you very much

CODE:

```
public class Player  implements InputProcessor {

    private Texture up;
    private Texture down;
    private Sprite player;

    public Player(Texture one,Texture two){

        this.up=one;
        this.down=two;
        player=new Sprite(one);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.setTexture(this.down);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.setTexture(this.up);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

I  implement the player class in this way, but I would like some suggestions for implementing best.

Comment: Could you add some code to illustrate your problem? I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to subclass very useful [`Sprite`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) class and use [TextureAtlas](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html) to contain player textures. here is the stub of implementation:

```
 public class Player extends Sprite {

    TextureAtlas textureAtlas;

    public Player(TextureAtlas atlas) {
        super(atlas.getRegions().get(0));
        textureAtlas = atlas;
    }

    public void setTexture(String textureName) {
        setRegion(textureAtlas.findRegion(textureName)));
    }

}
```

[Here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/02/LibGDX-Tutorial-3-Basic-graphics.aspx) is a very nice tutorial explaining how to use `TextureAtlas`.

Also, instead of implementing whole `InputProcessor`, use `InputAdapter` which provides an empty implementation of this interface. This will be [much more clearer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). It can be a field in your `Player` class:

```
   private InputProcessor inputProcessor = new InputAdapter() {
   // Override only methods you need here
   };
```

Of course, don't forget to register this InputProcessor:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

Comment: ok, but if I want to implement InputAdapter in other class in the key pressed events I have to change the texture of the player.From where I take the object player.  I do not know if I explained well

Comment: @dvdfrosiii Then you have to pass a reference of Player to this class somehow.

Comment: try setting the input proccessor within the Player class and override the functions. For example 
`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){@Override public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {}   
});`

Comment: In that case, the Player is the only thing that can catch the input, I would rather get it from the Screen (which is exactly what I did personally, and set the current screen as input processor in the `show()` method) and then do http://stackoverflow.com/a/24511980/2413303 although if you have an orthographic camera then you just need to use "camera.unproject" instead of having your own input transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I will update my answer with examples when i get home in a few hours.

It doesnt seem a good practice to listen for keys in the player class. I implemented a player class in my game some time ago and it was like this:

- in the render method of your game class you implement key listeners, that invoke player.up() or player.down() or for example player.jump().
- in player class in those methods, for example in jump() you set textures/animations.

I will post code examples.

```
public class Player {
float x;
float y;
float xSpeed;
float ySpeed;
private Animation playerRun;
private Animation playerJump;
private Animation playerStand;
private Animation current;
private Rectangle bounds;

public Player(){
    playerRun = new Animation(1/10f, Assets.atlas.findRegions("run"));
    playerRun.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);

    //set other animations in similar way

    current = playerStand;

    this.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2;
    this.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2;

    bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 100);
}

public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return bounds;
}

public void setPos(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    bounds.x = x;
    bounds.y = y;
}

public void changePos(float x, float y){
    this.x +=x;
    this.y +=y;
    bounds.x += x;
    bounds.y += y;
}

public void move(){
    changePos(xSpeed, ySpeed);
}

public Animation animate(){
    return current;
}

public void run(){
    current = playerRun;
    ySpeed = 0;
}

public void jump(){
    current = playerJump;
    ySpeed = 10;
}
```

and the render method in my game class was only calling players methods:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
                player.jump();
            }
```

oops, forgot the most important part :

```
batch.draw(player.animate().getKeyFrame(time += delta), player.x, player.y);
```