# libgdx - correcting for multiple coordinate origins?

Tags: java, libgdx, coordinates

I have a collision Rectangle (the libgdx one, not awt) set to a ball's coordinates. What I want to do is check if I've tapped on it. Two problems:
a.) I don't know where the origin of the rectangle's coordinates is.
b.) I can't find a way of correct way of correcting for the tap location.
What can I do?

Edit per request:

```
public void create() {
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

...

camera.unproject(tmpPos);
}

public void render() {
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            float x = Gdx.input.getX();
            float y = Gdx.input.getY();
            tmpPos.set(x, y, 0);
            camera.unproject(tmpPos);
            // now the world coordinates are tmpPos.x and tmpPos.y
            if (target.contains(tmpPos.x, tmpPos.y)) {
                System.out.println("Touched. ");
                score++;
            }

            System.out.println("Score: " + score + "..." + "X: " + (int) tmpPos.x + "...Y: " + (int) tmpPos.y);
        ...
        }
```

Comment: 1.) `setOrigin(0, 0);`
2.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501268/how-do-i-detect-if-a-sprite-was-touched-in-java-libgdx

Comment: although technically if you are using a `Camera` rather than your own `Matrix3` for orthographic transformation, then I think `camera.unproject()` can give you the coordinates of the tap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look and try these when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution was this:

Set the vector to the touch coordinates, however, with this correction: `(Gdx.input.getY() * -1) + cy` where `cy` is the height of the screen. I then unproject that vector, and draw it. Instead of the inverse y location I got without the correction, the circle follows directly under my finger and communicates with other objects in the world perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a orthographic camera. (you really can't make a game without it)

You don't need to know its origin to check if is touched, but if you want to, the origin is

```
float originX = rectangle.x + rectangle.width / 2f;
float originY = rectangle.y + rectangle.height / 2f;
```

Anyways, you will need to unproject your touch coordinates, this means that you need to translate from the screen position to the camera position (world position).
For this you need a Vector3, is prefered to declare it somewhere outside of the method you are using, because initializing a object in every frame is not recommended.

```
Vector3 tmpPos=new Vector3();
```

And now check if your rectangle is touched, anywhere you want.
You have 2 ways to do this.

1. Do this in the render / update method, checking the position of the finger / cursor.

public void render(float delta) {

```
   if (Gdx.input.isTouched() { // use .isJustTouched to check if the screen is touched down in this frame
            // so you will only check if the rectangle is touched just when you touch your screen.
            float x = Gdx.input.getX();
            float y = Gdx.input.getY();
            tmpPos.set(x, y, 0);
            camera.unproject(tmpPos);
            // now the world coordinates are tmpPos.x and tmpPos.y
            if (rectangle.contains(tmpPos.x, tmpPos.y)) {
                // your rectangle is touched
                System.out.println("YAAAY I'm TOUCHED");
            }

        }
    }
```

Options 2, use a input listener, so you only check when a touch event is triggered.
In the show / create method of your screen / game add your input listener

```
public void show() {

// .....
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {

    // and in the method that you want check if the rectangle is touched
    @override
    public void touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        tmpPos.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
        camera.unproject(tmpPos);
        // now the world coordinates are tmpPos.x and tmpPos.y
        if (rectangle.contains(tmpPos.x, tmpPos.y)) {
            // your rectangle is touched
            System.out.println("YAAAY I'm TOUCHED");
        }
    }

    // and the rest of the methods
    // ....
    //

});
```

}

I would use the second way.
let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I have `camera.unproject(tmpPos);` in my create() method, and your first method in render(). It doesn't seem to be working. It's reporting the coordinates from the center, and the only thing thus far that's doing so. I have my rectangle at `50, 50` which is the bottom left corner, and that's `-300, -460` with this.

Comment: Added in original question.

Comment: That is not full code, is just a part of it. Provide the full class. Pastebin it and link here

Comment: The full class is thousands of lines already. That's the only even remotely relevant part.

Comment: If your class is 1000 + lines that is bad..you don't want to make such a big class, using more classes is a better ideea. Anyways, that code should be working, 1) how do you draw your rectangle? 2) is the render method that you wrote called ?

Comment: I am using multiple classes, the main one just happens to be big. Not why I came here. Render is called every frame, yes.  
`target = new Rectangle(x, y, 64, 64);` is how I create the rectangle, and then I draw a texture on the same coordinates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61512/discussion-between-boldijar-paul-and-ihazabone).